# php - valid regEx expression in ereg_replace makes nothing

Tags: php, regex, posix-ere

I'm using PHP 5.2.17. I want to remove some surplus data from a JSON string and I've thought I can use some replace function to do so. Specifically I'm using ereg_replace with the next expression:

```
'^.*?(?=\"created_at)'
```

Which I've validated at http://www.regexpal.com. I've pasted my JSON string in there and the match is right. However, when I make the call:

```
$tweets = eregi_replace('^.*?(?=\"created_at)', $temp, 'something');
```

and then I echo the $tweets variable, there's output. No errors in console neither. Apache error log, however, complains about an error called REG_BADRPT. There's a comment in the php docs of eregi_replace suggesting this can be due to I need to escape special characters, but I've already escaped the " character. And I've tried to escape others but no different behavior.

Where could the problem be then?

Comment: Please don't use the `ereg` functions in PHP; they are deprecated. You should use `preg_replace()` instead.

Comment: you really should use `json_decode` and remove the data you don't need, then encode it back.

Comment: `$tweets = preg_replace('/^.*?(?=\"created_at)/', $temp, 'something');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `ereg` supports lookarounds.  `preg_replace` exists in php 5.2, so you should really use that instead.  It will work with your expression with delimiters.

```
$tweets = preg_replace('@^.*?(?=\"created_at)@i', 'something', $temp);
```

Comment: Note, however, that preg_replace changes the sort of the parameters: It should be `preg_replace('@^.*?(?=\"created_at)@i', 'something', $temp);`. Took me a whole while to figure out what was happening since this proposal wasn't working.

Comment: @JorgeAntonioDíaz-Benito fixed issue; next time it would help if you include the string to test with.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have pointed out, ereg functions are deprecated, so use preg_replace. You also have to encapsulate your regex string in slashes (`/`). You can put your regex flags after your last slash.

Comment: Although this is not the most straight-forward nor the quickest way for the solution between all proposals, this information is greatly appreciated, really.